# I have a matrix in Excel and I need a formula to look up 2 values within two separate ranges to yield a specific percentage

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

For example, the column headings of the matrix are compa-ratio ranges, 0-.90, .91-1.05, 1.06-2, etc. and the row headings are score ranges, 0-2, 2.01-2.50, 2.51-3, etc.  If your you compa-ratio is between 0-.90 & your score is between 2.51-3, then your increase 6%.

What formula can I use to lookup the compa-ratio value and the score value to yield the appropriate increase % from the matrix?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `VLOOKUP` and `MATCH`

By example:

```
    A    B   C   D
1     |  0  10  20 
    --|------------   
2   0 |  1   4   7
3   1 |  2   5   8
4   2 |  3   6   9
```

Cell A6 = `15`
Cell B6 = `1.5`
Cell C6 = `=VLOOKUP(B6,$A$2:$D$4,MATCH(A6,$A$1:$D$1,1),1)`
Result = `5`

How it works

1. `VLOOKUP` finds finds value in column A, using approximate match (returns row of largest value less than or equal to lookup value)
2. `MATCH`  finds finds value in Row 1, using approximate match (returns row of largest value less than or equal to lookup value)
3. `MATCH` is used to indicate to `VLOOKUP` which column to return